# Scala ctrl c not leave REPL

Tags: python, scala, shell

I comes from Python background and just begin to use scala.

In python shell, when I type in a command and find a typo in it, I usually use ctrl c to generate a keyboard Interrupt exception so that I can directly type the next statement. The previous statement won't be executed, and I'm still in Python shell.

But in Scala REPL, when I enter ctrl c, I'll immediately quit the Scala REP, which is annoying to me.

Is there anyway to make REPL works like python shell?

Scala version I'm using is 2.11.7. I'm using Mac.

Comment: just make your statement illegal by adding some meaningless characters, it won't be executed either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is even the right way to use Python REPL to abandon a mistyped command, there are several shortcuts probably will make your life easier [here](http://www.computerhope.com/ushort.htm).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> should be the command you are looking for.

> Erases the complete line.

Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will delete anything before the cursor, which should abandon the existing line completely if you are typing.
If your cursor is in the middle, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to go the end first, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

I tested in the shell, Python REPL and Scala REPL and they all work. 
For the curious minds:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will go to the beginning,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will delete the text after the cursor.

Comment: @jinxuanWu sure, if you think this is helpful, can you mark the answer as accepted solution so it is easier for future readers to find?

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Ammonite-REPL](https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL) by Li Haoyi. Among many other improvements, it does capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Note - Ammonite doesn't run on windows.